# How do I use export to make LLVM_SRC_ROOT equal to /llvm

Tags: linux, llvm, llvm-clang

How do I use export to make LLVM_SRC_ROOT equal to /llvm, which is where my llvm files are located ??
I have looked up export on the WEB, and I have tried to do as stated, but it does not work for me..
I entered ""export $LLVM_SRC_ROOT=/llvm""
and the computer stated that ""=/llvm : not a valid identifier""

THANK YOU Marty

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it right. For setting variables, you don't include the sigil:

```
export LLVM_SRC_ROOT=/llvm
```

If you want to make it permanent, add this to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file and logout